# New to excel, I wanted to ask if its possible to collect specific data from a table based on one input

Tags: excel, excel-formula, receipt

Here is my question. I have two sheets. one contains receipts of purchases on each page horizontally. The other contains parts of those receipts that are necessary for arranging product delivery.

For example. the receipts would have mattress name, size, price, amount, tax, total, paid, unpaid, location, customer name, phone number, all row names, all column names, and receipt number. On my other sheet, i want to be able to Make it so that it would take these values in that order and put them in a row:

Mattress name, Size, Amount, Customer name, Phone number, Location, Unpaid, and receipt number.

I want to somehow automate that so that when i put in like the receipt number it will get everything needed from that receipt and put it in said columns in that row. Is there any way to do that?

I basically want to be able to enter a receipt number and have some code filter out the info i need and put it in specific cells in this other sheet. The receipt would have images and colors and distinguishing features, but i want the delivery sheet to be formal organized and only has necessary information for deliver.

I have no experience with VDA code for excel, and only minimal experience with normal formulas. Any help would be much appreciated.

Thank you for your time.

Sample Data:

Receipt:
[image: Receipt]

Numbers represent order in Delivery (Subject to change if it makes it easier)

Delivery:
[image: Delivery Data]

Shows the delivery data table and what it looks like. I can change this and reorder this however I want but I still need all information In there for delivery. If changing the order makes it somehow easier then I can do that.

Comment: You can probably use an **AutoFilter**.  If you update your question with some data snapshots, we can help you with the details.

Comment: I have edited the question to add sample data with details in case you can help me. I would very much appreciate it. Thank you for your time :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done with a lookup formula, for example Vlookup or Index/Match.

To use Vlookup, the receipt number must be the first column of the receipts table, e.g. in the sheet **Receipts Table**, column A.

Then on the delivery sheet, you can enter a receipt number into a cell, say A1, and use this formula in another cell:

```
=vlookup($A$1,'Receipts Table'!$A:$Z,4,false)
```

The `4` in the formula means "return the value from the 4th column", and the count starts with the first column in the lookup range. In this formula, the lookup range is all columns from A to Z, so the 4th column will be D. If you want to return the value from column E, use 5, etc.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have added Sample data to the question to clarify my problem. I want to write code so that if i write the receipt number in that last section of the delivery table, It would look up the rest of the data from the actual receipt and input it as shown. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you :)

Comment: So you basically want this the other way around from what I suggested? You want to enter data into the Receipt form and that data should then be added to the Delivery table? That kind of data input form is quite complex. You will need to learn more about Excel and coding, then post your code and explain where you are stuck. We don't provide a free coding service on this site.

Comment: I have some Coding experience in C# and Python but not with excel. I dont even know where to start. And if its not free I mean how much do you expect? If its a reasonable price i could paypal you.

Comment: Sorry, I was not clear: We can help you write your own code if you post what you have written and explain where you are stuck. If you want to hire a developer, you need to look elsewhere.

Comment: Understandable. Well thank you for your time then @teylyn. I’ll try to figure out how to make progress on this and see where it goes. Have a fantastic day!